# Infinite loop while printing

Tags: c++, linked-list

First off I am brand new to C and have been thrown into a program in which I must use C. Now I believe my problem has something to do with a pointer, but when I try to print the list (to make sure I have stored it in the correct order my program crashes after the second time through the loop.

This is my insert function which inserts by the lowest time needed, and I believe it is right but have not been able to test it as my print crashes

```
void insertProcess(Process& process, Process* &head, Process* curr, Process* prev){
curr = head;
if(head == NULL){
    head = &process;
}
else{
    prev = head;
    while(process.timeNeeded > curr->timeNeeded){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    prev->next = &process;
    process.next = curr;
}
}
```

Here is my simple loop which should print the list. This will run a few times before giving an a 'access violation reading location'

```
while(curr->next != NULL){
    printf("%s %i %i %i\n", process.processName, process.arrivalTime,     process.timeNeeded, process.priority);
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

I am pretty sure the error would be in one of these segments of code, I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: OK with the help of the first poster I fixed the original problem, but now I have an infinite loop when printing. I am pretty sure it would be because I am inserting in order and never set a NULL pointer after the last item. Does that seem correct, and if so, is there any way to fix it? Thanks again

Comment: `Process *&head` isn't legal c. You can't pass by reference.

Comment: Are you compiling this with a c++ compiler?

Comment: Actually I am, its what I was familiar with and what my class was doing as we had no knowledge of C, nor time to learn it. The real reason we were using C was so we wouldn't use object oriented properties of c++. And I knew that didn't seem right when I did it but head was being reset every time I called insert, if there is another way to do this I will gladly fix it.

Comment: In c, you would pass head as `Process **head`. You could then use `(*head)->field`, and `*head = newhead`. That way, a c compiler would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you are passing a `Process` **by value** and this means that the function will work on a local copy of the `Process` object that will be destroyed when the function exits.

Your code however is linking in this local copy and therefore once you exit the function your linked list is now using a `Process` object that has been already destroyed.

Another problem is that when looping to search the insertion point you are not considering the case that the inserted process may be the last one and in that case `curr` will become NULL in the loop.

Comment: Thanks that fixed one problem, one I should've seen. I'm getting an infinite loop now printing the last item I inserted only, but maybe I can find the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use a debugger. On Linux you should compile with both `-g` (to get debugging information produced by the compiler) and `-Wall` (to get all warnings) passed to `gcc` or `g++`. Then you can use the `gdb` debugger on your executable.